# How to get add edit functionality when click on hyperlink and edit the records from XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, code-behind

I have a dynamic grid.
When i click on a record my screen opens but the id can show all the records to make a add edit functionality so that i can change it and update it.

2 pages I do have

1)DisplayData.aspx
2)AddMaster.aspx

I have a  grid on which I can see the records in Display Data and the view of the screen from which The rerecords are added are in AddMaster.aspx

Code as Follows:

DisplayData.aspx

```
function FillEditScreen(iID)
    {  
    window.location = "AddMaster.aspx?txtLocationID=" + iID;
    }
```

Now I am able to get the record ID

Now passing to AddMaster.aspx in which Record I can update so that it can open and i can edit and update it.Now also passing a function Here:named:     fncFillControls

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string ID = Request.QueryString["txtLocationID"];


if (ID != null)
        {

            fncFillControls(ID);
        }

}
```

Getting Id Successfully Here:
Data.XML is the file in which My data is getting Saved.

Now the function Detention

```
public void fncFillControls(string UserID )
    {
        try
        {

            string filepathClassidID3 = Server.MapPath("~/Data.xml");
            DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
            ds3.ReadXml(filepathClassidID3);

            for (int i = 0; i <= ds3.Tables["CD"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                if (ds3.Tables["CD"].Rows[i]["LocationID"].ToString() == UserID)
                {
                    txtlocation01.Text = ds3.Tables["CD"].Rows[i]["LocationID"].ToString();
                    break;
                }

            }


        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

My data.xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />

  <CD>
    <LocationID>Test121</LocationID>
    <ChangeValueFor>TestFor India</ChangeValueFor>
    <Banner>India</Banner>
    <DataEntry>Yes</DataEntry>
    <LocalView>Yes</LocalView>
    <Export>Yes</Export>
    <View>Illions</View>
    <ActiveView>Kentency</ActiveView>
    <HelpFile>Finger</HelpFile>
    <Location01>Chicken</Location01>
    <Location02>India</Location02>
    <Location03>USa</Location03>
    <Location04>Africa</Location04>
    <Location05>USa</Location05>
    <Location06>Ellions</Location06>
    <Location07>UK</Location07>
    <Location08>States</Location08>
    <Location09>OF</Location09>
    <Server>31 March 2014 testing with font</Server>
    <Server2>171.21.102.11</Server2>
    <Server3>test2</Server3>
    <CodeBase>Ser</CodeBase>
    <CodeBase2>31 amrch testing for font</CodeBase2>
    <CodeBase3>hellow</CodeBase3>
    <ClassiscID>clsid:ACAC1200-0BBE-499A-A9E9-5F334DBC8E89</ClassiscID>
    <ClassiscID2>clsid:ACAC1200-0BBE-499A-A9E9-5F334DBC8E89</ClassiscID2>
    <ClassiscID3>this</ClassiscID3>
    <Theme>class</Theme>
    <Theme2>Theme2</Theme2>
    <Theme3>Ser</Theme3>
    <Theme4>InkIndia</Theme4>
    <Theme5>InkIndia</Theme5>
    <Theme6>VashnoDevi</Theme6>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Now I want to open a record and when I click on it all the things will open in Addmaster.aspx page.But It is getting id but comes with no id and i can edit the records because all the feild is empty just like we do in add functionlaity.

Comment: Is your userid "Test121" or just "121"?

Comment: Test 121.....LocationID is a unique id

Comment: I can't find issue.  The code properly reads the xml file and loads "Test121" into the textbox.

Comment: Like we have identity in SQL which generates a unique auto generated id is their any thing same in xml also.I want my record to be unique on basis of id.so how can i not give any tag as id and make a record with a uinique id in xml in asp.net

Comment: Unique ids are simply an integer where you increment a counter to get next number.  When an application starts you either find the highest number already assign and then increment unique counter, or save the highest number in a file.